# htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, apache

I just inherited an ExpressionEngine site from someone without much documentation for how it was put together. I'm trying to set up some 301 redirects, but the htaccess file is being ignored. I have a file named .htaccess in the same directory as our index file, yet it isn't being read.

Our IT department says that AllowOverride in Apache is set to "all," and they suspect that the problem is within ExpressionEngine. Is there a place within ExpressionEngine where htaccess can be enabled/disabled, or is this an Apache thing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to increase your chances of getting useful answers it would be worth adding some further details to your question, plus some sample code if possible.

Comment: .htaccess is loaded by apache and the rules are processed every time a request is made. without being able to look at your actual file it's hard to say but my guess would be that the syntax is wrong or something in the file is overriding the processing of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Here's what I have in the htaccess file:

```
# Standard .htaccess file

# Secure .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Redirect 301 /index.php/info_resources/sites http://www.cptc.edu/index.php/site_directory/


# Don't show any directory without an index file
Options -Indexes

# Dont list files in index pages
IndexIgnore *

# EE 404 page for missing pages
# May differ depending on where your template is located.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?/site/404
```